# Python Radio Stream from URL

Tags: python, streaming, raspberry-pi, audio-streaming

I want to be able to stream a radio station using python, in particular on a raspberry pi. I've found lots of DIYs for raspberry pi radios, but most focus on bells and whistles like input dials that allow the device to mimic an actual radio. All I want (and cannot seem to be able to figure out) is a package with a function that I can pass a URL within a script such that it will play the radio from that URL for a certain amount of time. So, for example, the pseudocode would be:

```
import package as radio
radio.play(url, playtime = 60)
```

The `radiopy` package seeming should have this feature, but the [tutorial](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/radiopy/) I found focuses on using it as a command line tool and I can't find an example of how to use the package in a script like in the pseudocode above.

Comment: Not sure if you are still looking for the answer but i think you should have a look at vlc bindings for python. Don't draw the frames and you can directly pass the url over. Here is the link https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc

Comment: I found a solution, I should write it up. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Hi @Michael what was the solution you found?

Comment: Hi Michael, did you find a solution?